# jcarousel and database query

Tags: php, jquery

im using a jcarousel:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        vertical: true,

         auto: 3,
         wrap: 'circular'


    })
})
```

so it is a circular config , i have a query like this :

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_insujets, my_inmessages WHERE my_insujets.insujets_idforum = my_inmessages.inmessages_idsujet ORDER BY inmessages_date DESC LIMIT 6");
```

so the carousel shows 3 rows then the other 3 rows, but after this it keeps on in a loop where nothing is showed.

```
    <div id="wrap">
       <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel jcarousel-skin-tango">

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql) ) {  ?>
       <li>
       <?php echo $row["message"]; ?>
  </li>  
               <?php  }  ?>
        </ul>
           </div>
```

Comment: can you provide the rendered html after executing php....

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the problem, but it appears that your `<li>` tags are not closed.

Comment: sorry this was just a typo error, just edited it.Not the real problem.

Comment: Can you post your HTML from View Source?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an end `</li>` in your example code.